# Delete or Assign to null arrays inside the object Angular 8

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, angular8

I have a complex object of type:

```
obj{
    insideObj{
             abc [],
             data[
                  innerObj1{
                            'string1.1',
                            'string1.2',
                            insideArray1.1[some data inside],
                            insideArray1.2[some data inside]
                           },
                  innerObj2{
                            'string2.1',
                            'string2.2',
                            insideArray2.1[some data inside],
                            insideArray2.2[some data inside]
                           }
                 ]
              }
    }
```

Inside the data array I am changing the values of string1 and string2 and I want to either set `insideArray1 and insideArray2` equal to zero or simply remove them before sending into the post API call. So the end object should look like:

```
obj{
    insideObj{
             abc [],
             data[
                  innerObj1{
                            'string1.1',
                            'string1.2',
                            insideArray1.1[] (should be null), // should either the entire data be null
                            insideArray1.2[] (should be null)  // should either the entire data be null
                           },
                  innerObj2{
                            'string2.1', // should either be deleted
                            'string2.2',
                           }
                 ]
              }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? When you set string1/2, just also set insideArray accordingly or delete it?

Comment: that exactly the issue is. How to delete an array?

Comment: You can just delete a property from a javascript object with `delete`: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete